# publishedAfter parameter appears to be broken now

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I used daily this request to googleapi in my application:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=25&order=date&publishedAfter=2019-03-15T18%3A01%3A02.000Z&publishedBefore=2019-03-17T09%3A58%3A15.000Z&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

Timestamps were of course changed each time. This worked fine till yesterday. Today this command did not work properly and returns results from different *(much larger)* time period.

Their timestamps are 25 and appear random:

```
"2018-10-04T10:06:56.000Z"
"2015-03-05T16:55:26.000Z"
"2018-09-24T08:05:59.000Z"
"2019-03-10T14:22:14.000Z"
"2018-07-24T19:08:39.000Z"
"2018-10-08T22:34:22.000Z"
"2018-09-10T11:38:37.000Z"
"2019-01-05T18:45:24.000Z"
"2019-02-12T07:00:07.000Z"
"2016-08-20T09:53:44.000Z"
"2018-10-20T21:31:43.000Z"
"2014-04-18T13:05:31.000Z"
"2019-01-24T14:00:30.000Z"
"2018-12-05T11:34:23.000Z"
"2019-03-04T13:59:05.000Z"
"2019-02-18T19:08:52.000Z"
"2018-12-24T11:33:56.000Z"
"2019-02-25T16:30:57.000Z"
"2017-07-07T16:44:59.000Z"
"2019-03-08T17:01:07.000Z"
"2019-02-04T12:49:42.000Z"
"2018-10-01T09:38:39.000Z"
"2015-09-18T22:52:30.000Z"
"2017-05-23T17:43:09.000Z"
"2019-03-13T17:59:24.000Z"
```

Is something broken?

Comment: can you post the timestamps of the results you have gotten?

Comment: @TomerShahar - added in the original question.

Comment: @TomerShahar - interestingly, the same set of results is returned on every run.

Comment: @TomerShahar - I updated the http request in the question to the exact one my app is using with `&order=date`, in case it is critical...

Comment: Same here for about 2 days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like it is a global problem.
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/2494861?hl=en

Comment: 12 days, ~3900 upvotes on Google forums but the bug is still there